# How to use pandas duplicate filter duplicate value except empty string

Tags: pandas

I have a `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '']})`. If I use `df.duplicated()` directly on df, I will get 2,4 are duplicated. Is there a way that I can only get duplicate row with value, ignore empty string?

Comment: You can't directly, you need to combine it with a second mask. For example: `df['col1'].duplicated() & df['col1'].ne('')`